# Why do special characters in search terms are processed as encoded characters (only on Production Server)?

Tags: magento-1.6, url-rewrite, search, htaccess, 301-redirect

**This issue only happens once the site has been deployed to *Production Server*.  On *Development Environment* works as expected.**

Using Magento 1.6.2.0 CE, Locale: español (Spanish)

Search works just fine on **Development Environment** when using search terms that contain special characters (latin characters in this case: á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ, etc.), but when website is moved to **Production Server**, search breaks with special characters.

Everything else seems to be working fine, I haven't found any other encoding issue so far.

I tried adding **AddDefaultCharset UTF-8** to **.htaccess** file with no avail.

I don't think it's a server configuration issue, because **Production Server** hosts other websites (mostly Joomla!) that fully support special characters in search terms.

For reference try to search for term with special characters like "brócoli" on http://caserisimo.mx

### On Development Environment:

[image: Development Environment]

### On Production Server:

[image: Production Server]

Any ideas?

Your help will be much appreciated.

---

### ** UPDATE **

I use a 301 redirect in .htaccess for URL trailing slashes removal with directives:

```
RewriteCond %{request_method} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks to @MatthiasZeis great suggestion, I added the **NE** flag to the last directive, so now the RewriteRule is:

```
RewriteCond %{request_method} ^GET$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Works as expected now!

Comment: Please mark @matthias' answer as correct if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I noticed was that the search returns an 301 redirect with the HTTP header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` and the wrong URL `http://caserisimo.mx/catalogsearch/result?q=br%25C3%25B3coli`.

Your search result page has the correct `UTF-8` content type. I guess you want to find out where that redirect is coming from.

Comment: I use a 301 redirect in **.htaccess** for URL trailing slashes removal.  Do you think this could affect?

Comment: I guess so. The browser sends the URL request `http://caserisimo.mx/catalogsearch/result?q=br%C3%B3coli` and the redirect transforms it to `http://caserisimo.mx/catalogsearch/result?q=br%25C3%25B3coli` (replacing `%` with `%25`). If you set back the URL in the browser location bar to `caserisimo.mx/catalogsearch/result?q=br%C3%B3coli` the search works. Did you set the `NE` flag when redirecting (see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479403/htaccess-redirect-urls-with-utf-8-chars))?

Comment: I have updated my original question, your suggestion works like a charm, Matthias.